# Can Eclipse take libraries from an internet repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, eclipse-plugin

We can easily do that in Gradle or Maven or Ant+Ivy - we only set a dependency and the framework takes the necessary jar from the internet. But what if we have pure Eclipse project? I am now working on one large product(60ppl*15years) that uses Eclipse plugins, but no Gradle or such. And I don't want to make people to download jars to all computers where the product works.

Can I, using Eclipse itself, import a library from the Internet repository? Or any automatic addition of four jars into the product without changing the principles of use of already existing jars.

Comment: What do you mean by _"import a library"_? Only downloading the JAR file from a known URL? If you want to do this, for example, you can do it with Ant (Ant is built-in and can automatically be triggered as [project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm)). Otherwise, make an example with a step-by-step instruction of the manual steps that should be automated.

Comment: A Target Platform containing plug-ins can be automatically downloaded from an update site.

Comment: No, I can't do it with Ant (BTW, not Ant, but Ivy does it for ant). Neither Maven or Gradle. It is a large product (60ppl*15years) that runs on Eclipse and nobody wants to change the principles of building.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understood correctly, you're building a product based upon the Eclipse platform?

Comment: @thokuest Yes, upon Eclipse, all additional libraries are imported as plugins.